# How do I access the body content of a POST in Grails?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to read the body content of a Grails request and it's mapping the request to the params even though I've commented out the grails.mime.types. I've also tried setting grails.mime.types to and empty map and it's still mapping.

The body content is xml and when Grails maps it, the key ends up being "<?xml version". Unfortunately, the system sending the POST is setting the content-type to *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*. I don't have control over them changing it.

I'm running Grails 1.2.1.

I've also tried setting format="xml" in my UrlMappings and adding the form content type to the xml mime.types but that didn't help either. And when I try to access the request.reader, it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling 'parseRequest' in your mapping.

From the [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/guide/webServices.html#REST): "Grails will not provide automatic XML or JSON marshaling for you unless you specify the parseRequest argument in the URL mapping".

Comment: The webpage must have changed.  Searching for "parseRequest" yields nothing.

Comment: There is no "parseRequest" on the page the given URL points to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the request.reader directly instead of having the XML unmarshalled to a domain object, then try turning off `parseRequest` like this:

class UrlMappings {

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"(parseRequest:false){
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

}

I got this solution from: http://margotskapacs.com/2013/04/request-automatic-parsing-in-grails/